# How to Fetch Monthly Attendance report by student?

Tags: mysql

I got student_id=14 through form post and I need to fetch attendance report for the student_id as below

```
CLASS   STUDENT_ID  YEAR    MONTH   TOTAL_CLASSES   TOTAL_PRESENT

11      14      2016       April          21             20
11      14      2016       May            25             25
11      14      2016       June           30             29
11      14      2016       July           18             18
11      14      2017       January        28             28
```

Here TOTAL_CLASSES represents total number days school is open and TOTAL_PRESENT represents total number of says a student is present out of TOTAL_CLASSES.

From HTML Form I GOT only student_id=14 and I need to fetch and show record as above.

Please see sqlfiddle here to support my answer  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63b6a/3

In my table remarks represents 1,2,3 for present and 0 for absent.

Comment: You need a calendar table,esentially a table with 12 ints,LEFT JOIN on that to get all the months

Comment: Please sqlfiddle only that table is available for the attendance and to know how many days school is open i need to find the class_id of the student and then count the total att_date for the particular class month wise to get TOTAL_CLASSES

Answer (score 1):

You're counting attendance numbers for each `year`, `month`, `class` and `student`. The key step in this query is to use `GROUP BY` to indicate the columns which you're grouping, then use the COUNT and SUM aggregation functions to compute the attendance columns you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
  class_id, 
  student_id, 
  YEAR(att_date) as year, 
  MONTH(att_date) as month, 
  COUNT(remarks) AS total_classes,
  SUM(remarks > 0) AS total_present
FROM attendance
WHERE student_id = 15
GROUP BY YEAR(att_date), MONTH(att_date), class_id, student_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63b6a/11

You can remove the WHERE clause to show attendance for all students.